# React Native, How this mixins works as a Timer?

Tags: javascript, timer, reactjs, react-native, mixins

I'm learning the react native, And the following Mixins used to clear the timer after `Umount`, But I get confused by the following code:
[From Reusable Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html)

```
var SetIntervalMixin = {
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.intervals = [];
  },
  setInterval: function() {
    this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.intervals.forEach(clearInterval);
  }
};

var TickTock = React.createClass({
  mixins: [SetIntervalMixin], // Use the mixin
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {seconds: 0};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setInterval(this.tick, 1000); // Call a method on the mixin
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({seconds: this.state.seconds + 1});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>
        React has been running for {this.state.seconds} seconds.
      </p>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <TickTock />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

questions:
What does this means:

```
setInterval: function() {
    this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
},
```

When I try to use the `setTimeout` :

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({seconds: this.state.seconds + 0.5}), 500); // Call a method on the mixin
},
```

but the timer not worked.

Comment: Hey @herbertD, I don't know how urgent you need this clarification though, Here is a blogpost: http://www.darul.io/post/2016-01-05_react-higher-order-components.

Comment: Thanks Jyd, this post is what I want.

Comment: The url that Jyd provided don't work.

Comment: folow the https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#mixins